# Cancelling a background worker without worker.CancellationPending check?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a `Validator` class which has a `Validate` function, This validate function loops over bunch of file and validates them. User can cancel the validate process.

For cancelling the back ground worker I need ta reference of the background worker instance in Validtor class (for cancelling the validation process) and call `CancellationPending` on it.

But the problem is  Validator class can't have reference to background worker because there are times when we call the "Validate" function synchronously and Validator class does not have to know this.

So far  I have tried replacing  `backgroundworker.CancellationPending` check with some flag e.g. `IsCanceled` which do not seems to work.

Comment: You could wrap your work in a `while(!Abort)` call and set the field, but I would suggest you look into using `Task` for performing CPU intensive work, which supports `CancellationTokens`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Make two overloads of the `Validate` method. One that is synchronous and one that is asynchronous and cancellable.
2. Change your `Validate` method so that the calling code is responsible for looping over the files (consider an iterator method, using `yield`)

I'd go with option 1 as it is a smaller change.

Comment: the problem is I can't keep reference of background worker in the validate class, because validation logic does not have to know whether it was run in a background thread or not. second option is not possible because i have different types of Validator classes each implementing "IValidate" interface.

Comment: @naveen my solution was to _provide the facility for asynchronous operation on the validtor_. If you want to be able to cancel mid operation, the code that implements the operation must change.